# Join album with its images count and cover?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get a certain results from two tables using MySQL, below is the format of the two tables:

```
          Albums                                         Images
------------------------------                 ----------------------------
  id   |   name  |   cover                       id |   image     | album
------------------------------                 ----------------------------
  1    | album1  |    3                          1  | image1.jpg  |   2
  2    | album2  |    1                          2  | image2.jpg  |   3
  3    | album3  |    0                          3  | image3.jpg  |   1
  4    | album4  |    0                          4  | image4.jpg  |   1
------------------------------                   5  | image5.jpg  |   3
                                                 6  | image6.jpg  |   1
                                               ----------------------------
```

Now given the tables above, I'd like a result to look like this:

```
---------------------------------------
  id  |  name  |  count |  cover
---------------------------------------
  1   | album1 |   3    |  image3.jpg
  2   | album2 |   1    |  image1.jpg
  3   | album3 |   2    |    null
  4   | album4 |   0    |    null 
---------------------------------------
```

- `count` is the number of images in a given album
- `cover` is the image with the id that matches what is in the albums cover column

I have tried a few queries but none of them give me the desired results.

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.name, 
       count(p.id) AS imageCount, 
       (SELECT image 
          FROM albums, 
               photos 
         WHERE albums.cover = photos.id)
  FROM photos p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN albums a
              ON a.id=p.album
  GROUP BY a.id;
```

Which just results in listing the same cover image for each row.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.name, 
       count(p.id) AS imageCount, 
       coverTable.image
  FROM photos p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN albums a
              ON a.id=p.album
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT albums.id, 
                         image 
                     FROM albums, 
                          photos 
                    WHERE albums.cover = photos.id) AS coverTable
              ON coverTable.id = a.id
        GROUP BY a.id;
```

That only results in a single row for the one album that has a cover image.

Comment: Please don't put tables side by side. It makes it really hard to copy and paste into sqlfiddle.

Comment: Didn't think about that @Barmar, sorry. I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(p1.id) AS imageCount, p2.image as cover
FROM albums a
LEFT JOIN photos p1 ON p1.album = a.id
LEFT JOIN photos p2 ON p2.id = a.cover
GROUP BY a.id
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba3dd/1)</kbd>

Comment: I was two seconds slow with the same answer +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id
    ,a.name 
    ,(select COUNT(album) from @Img where album=a.id ) as cont
    ,i.imagename as cover from @albums a
left outer join @Img i on a.cover = i.id
```